# excel pattern fill depending of that 2 cells are equal

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA-code that change the pattern fill when 2 other cells are equal to each. I have the follow code:

```
        Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'       Macro2 Macro

'            If (H5)=(J20) Then
             Range("H7").Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        If (H5) <> (J20) Then
            Range("H7").Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
       End With
            Range("M20").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
       End If

       End Sub
```

The first part of the code is working but when you change one of the 2 cells then the pattern is not changed back in no Filling. What is wrong in the code?

Now is the macro only running when you open the workbook. Is it possible that the macro directly is running when you changed a cell?

Now I write the macro for Cell H7 that compares H5 with J20. I want that the macro H5 compares with J20:J29, is this possible one a "easy" way?

Last question: Is it also possible to use the macro for more cells in the same sheet, for example E5-E7,F5-F7,G5-G7,.....NK5-NK7 with the same kollom to compare (J20:J29)?

Yes, its a kind of conditional formatting. But I can't find the right formula/code for conditional formatting a cell by compare 2 other cells.
E.g. "E7 is gray when the date in E5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise E7 is not filled" and
     "F7 is gray when the date in F5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise f7 is not filled" and that so on up to 
     "NK7 is gray when the date in NK5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise NK7 is not filled".

Comment: Yes, its a kind of conditional formatting. But I can't find the right formula/code for conditional formatting a cell by compare 2 other cells.
E.g. "E7 is gray when the date in E5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise E7 is not filled" and
"F7 is gray when the date in F5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise f7 is not filled" and that so on up to "NK7 is gray when the date in NK5 is equal on the date in J20 or J21 or J22 or ... or J29 otherwise NK7 is not filled".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this.

With range E7:NK7 selected click on Contitional Formatting...New Rule... Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

In the formula box enter `=MATCH(E5,$J$20:$J$29,0)>0` and then set your format.

Delete your `Workbook_Open` code too, otherwise the conditional format in E7 will be replaced when you next open your workbook.

Comment: With this formula I don't reach my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in Conditional formatting. I have put the follow formula in a hidden row 
`=ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$20);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$21);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$22);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$23);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$24);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$25);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$26);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$27);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$28);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$29);1;ALS(GELIJK(E5;$J$30);1;0)))))))))))`

The pattern fill is now depending of a "0" of a "1".
Its working perfect. By using (or not using) $ in the formula by cell-numbers is it easy to copy the formula to other cells.
p.s. `ALS(dutch)=IF(English)` and `GELIJK(dutch)=MATCH(English)`